# coda slider active tab issue

Tags: javascript, css

I have extracted the coda slider from this site `http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/1.1.1/`. Panel 1 is in active state when open the site. I need the second panel as an active panel when open the site. This is the internal script that i have used.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
            jQuery("div#slider1").codaSlider()
            // jQuery("div#slider2").codaSlider()
            // etc, etc. Beware of cross-linking difficulties if using multiple sliders on one page.
        });
    </script>
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try use coda-slide 2.0 (http://www.ndoherty.biz/tag/coda-slider/) with option

"firstPanelToLoad: 3"

Coda-slider 1.1 does not support default selected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).bind("load", function() {
            jQuery("div#slider1").codaSlider({firstPanelToLoad: 2});
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

coda slider is using anchors. just add "#2" to your link